# Passing as argument to Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, keyup

I have the below HTML form and Javascript is used to validate the HTML form, so there is a hidden P element just below the text field to show if any errors in the field above it, there is a keyup event set on the (fn textfield) that triggers and hides the P (ID = fnp) element based on the input in the name (ID = fn) field this code works fine but I want it to be dynamic such that i dont have to write the same code again and again for each text field, I want to call the norml function and pass arguments into the norml function (an element name) so that it can do the same for each text field, but this method is not working : ANYBODY WOULD LIKE TO GUIDE ME WHAT I'M DOING WRONG HERE.

This is what I want to do which doesnt work:

```
document.getElementById("fn").onkeyup = norml(pass an element name);

function norml(value received)
document.getelementbyID(received element ID name).color = red;
```

EXAMPLE:

```
function norml(dx, dxx)  // receives a value as argument that is an element ID
{
    dx.style.borderColor = '#d6d6d6';
    dx.style.color = '#000000';
    dxx.style.innerHTML = '';
    dxx.style.visibility = 'hidden';    
}
```

THIS IS WHAT IS WORKING BUT WILL HAVE TO BE DONE FOR EACH TEXT FIELD INDIVIDUALLY

```
function norml()
{
    document.getElementById("fn").style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
    document.getElementById("fn").style.color = '#FF0000';
    document.getElementById("fnp").style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
    document.getElementById("fnp").style.innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("fnp").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}

function validate() {
    var errmsg = "";
    var result = true;

    var fname = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    if (!fname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))
        {
            document.getElementById("fn").style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
            document.getElementById("fn").style.color = '#FF0000';
            document.getElementById("fnp").style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
            document.getElementById("fnp").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("fnp").innerHTML = "Please enter first name in alphabets";
            document.getElementById("fn").onkeyup = norml;
            return false;
        }
    if (errmsg != ""){   //only display message box if there is something to show
    alert(errmsg);
}
}

function init()
{
    var formData = document.getElementById("enqForm");
    formData.onsubmit = validate;
}

window.onload = init;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="scripts.js"></script> 
<title></title> 
</head>
<body id="enquire">
<section id="form">
    <div>
    <form id="enqForm" method="post">
        <div class="formobj">
            <div id="enquiry"><h1></h1></div>
                <input id="fn" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name *" />
                <input id="ln" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name *" />
                <p id="fnp" type="hidden"></p>
                <p id="lnp" type="hidden"></p>
                    <input id="sendbutton" type="submit" value="Enquire" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

THANKS..

Answer (score 1):

Amongst other problems, the primary one is that you're setting the (undefined) *result* of calling `norml(dx, dxx)` in the `.onkeyup` property, instead of passing a function reference:

```
dx.onkeyup = function() {
    norml(dx, dxx);
}
```

The other problems include:

- repeated calls to obtain the same element over and over
- and then repeated calls to deference that element's style object
- use of DOM0 `.onXXX` instead of DOM3 `addEventListener`

Comment: Sir the code is not complete, its just test code and I'm a beginner...but thanks any way...